# Django, can't authenticate certain user

Tags: django, postgresql

All users in my django app can login (and thus pass the authentication). However there is a certain user that I can't login. I don't have any clue why that happens. I am using Django 1.5.8 and postgresql 9.2

Take a look at this:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=364)
>>> user
<User: GR006047>
>>> user.username
u'GR006047'
>>> user.set_password('123')
>>> user = authenticate(username='GR006047', password='123')
>>> user
>>> user == None
True
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah... You didn't save the user. i.e `user.save()`

Answer (score 2):

based on the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

> Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object.

So you need to save the user object after setting password:

```
>>> user.set_password('123')
>>> user.save()
>>> user = authenticate(username='GR006047', password='123')
```